# Store data in FragmentStatePager or ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a `FragmentStatePager`(or a `ViewPager`) and it contains on every page a `ListView`.The user should be able to add values dynamically into it.

So my question is :What is the best way to store these entries?

Comment: EditText into Listview

Comment: You want to store an `EditText` in a `ListView`?

Comment: I think what you need is to store the entries in a database or use shared preferences. But I think an SQLite database is neater and better for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data from the `ListView` in an `ArrayList` which you can keep track of in the `PagerAdapter`.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
   private ArrayList<T>[] mData;

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return mData.length;
   }

   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ArrayList<T> listViewData = mData[position];
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setData(listViewData);
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I had an array adapter but it doesn't stored the entries. Do this example store the data really?

Comment: Each ListView should have its own ArrayAdapter. The data for that will be set when we call fragment.setData(listViewData). When the data is modified, so will mDad stored in PagerAdapter since Java is pass by reference.